# What does this button do in the Twitter app?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, twitter

I tried to find the answer online but I couldn't.  In the screenshot what does the circled button do?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That button is for replying to a tweet

Comment: Wow, I feel stupid...I was wondering what it did because I see on my own tweet so I thought it had a different use than replying....thanks.

Comment: actually, when i press reply on my own tweet why does it not show my handle and only the hsndle of the person I was tweeting to....you sure that button still means "reply" when it's below our own tweet?